# ADB - Empty list of devices when running 'adb devices' command

Tags: android, mobile, adb, data-recovery, fastboot

I've a Honor 10 View Lite with a broken screen (it's not usable) and I would try to recover data from it.
Following some tutorials it seems possibile to do that with ADB and the phone in recovery mode (holding power button + volume up).
I've installed ADB drivers through UniversalAdbDriver.msi and Fastboot version 1.4.3 Portable on Windows 10.
Being the screen black it's difficult to understand if the phone reboot in custom recovery mode or in normal mode, but when I open shell on the same folder of Fastboot and type ***'adb devices'*** no device is found. I've also tried connecting another phone in recovery mode (Huawei Mate 10 Pro perfectly working) but the problem is still the same, no device found.

What can be the problem? Some wrong or missing installations?
I also have to specify that both the phones have USB debugging disabled and I hope this is not a problem because in the broken phone it's impossible to find a way to enable it. That's also the reason why I'm trying to recover data through ADB and not through programs like FoneLab and so on that required USB debugging enabled.

I will also accept advices on solutions different from ADB to recover data in these conditions, if they exists.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adb will work for this unless usb debugging is enabled. At least, the device might show up in "adb devices" list, but it would show up as "unauthorized" and you wouldn't be able to pull data off it.

What kind of data are you trying to retrieve? Don't suppose you have cloud backup?

If it's just the screen that's broken maybe you can find a way to mirror the screen onto an external display somehow.

Comment: The main problem is that screen is broken and maybe also the touch is not working anymore, so trying with app like ApowerMirror that requires to use it to select options as "Transfer file" or similar becomes very difficult. Unfortunately I've just checked Google Drive and there is no significant backup. Data I would like to retrieve are notes of an app that (unfortunately again) is not Google Keep.